# How to populate a TableView with data from Firebase Firestore?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

I am very new to iOS development (with emphasis on very). I think I have grasped simple table views in Xcode without calling on a database, and I also think I understand the basics of how to call data from Firestore, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to populate my TableView with data from Firestore.

The Firestore collection I want to populate with is called "articles", where each doc represents an article I want to display in a cell. Each doc has this structure of data:

```
imageURL: https://someurl.com
title: 5 places you don't want to miss
```

I have created a UITableView with a UITableViewCell inside it in Storyboard, where the TableViewCell's ContentView contains an ImageView for the 'imageURL' data in Firestore and a Label for the 'title' data in Firetore.

The UITableView in Storyboard is linked to ArtiklerTableViewController.swift.

Likewise is the UITableViewCell linked to ArtiklerCell.swift.

The two Swift files look like this now:

**ArtiklerTableViewController.swift**

```
class ArtiklerTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var artiklerTableView: UITableView!

    var artiklerArray: [String] = []
    var documents: [DocumentSnapshot] = []

    var db: Firestore!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        db = Firestore.firestore()
        configureTableView()
        loadData()

    func configureTableView() {
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(ArtiklerCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ArtiklerCell")

        // remove separators for empty cells
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        // remove separators from cells
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    }


    func loadData() {
        db.collection("articles").getDocuments() { (QuerySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents : \(err)")
            }
            else {
                for document in QuerySnapshot!.documents {
                    let documentID = document.documentID
                    let artiklerImageView = document.get("imageURL") as! URL
                    let artiklerTitleLabel = document.get("title") as! String
                    print(artiklerImageView, artiklerTitleLabel, documentID)
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        } 
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("Tableview setup \(artiklerArray.count)")
        return artiklerArray.count
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ArtiklerCell", for: indexPath) as! ArtiklerCell

        let artikler = artiklerArray[indexPath.row]

        print("Array is populated \(artiklerArray)")

        return cell
    }

}
```

**ArtiklerCell.swift**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ArtiklerCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var artiklerImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var artiklerTitleLabel: UILabel!

    var db: Firestore!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        db = Firestore.firestore()
        addSubview(artiklerImageView)
        addSubview(artiklerTitleLabel)
        configureImageView()

    }


    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    func configureImageView() {
        artiklerImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        artiklerImageView.clipsToBounds = true
    }   

}
```

When I try to run the app, I get an error message from the ArtiklerTableViewController.swift regarding the line `let artikler = artiklerArray[indexPath.row]` in the cellForRowAt function, saying 'Initialization of immutable value 'artikler' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it'.

I see that this error message makes sense, but I have absolutely no idea what I should do instead.

Pardon my extreme lack of knowledge! I have spent many days now trying to look for the answers I need online without finding a solution. I think I am too inexperienced to correctly search for and absorb the necessary knowledge for this problem.

Any answer will be immensely appreciated!

Thanks in advance from a desperate girl who doesn't want to give up on learning iOS dev as I go through building an app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the strings in an array and got the `artikler` corresponding to the row of the cell, now you just need to set the title and the image. Also, you need to append each element to the array before reloading.

```
func loadData() {
    db.collection("articles").getDocuments() { (QuerySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents : \(err)")
        }
        else {
            for document in QuerySnapshot!.documents {
                let documentID = document.documentID
                let artiklerImageView = document.get("imageURL") as! URL
                let artiklerTitleLabel = document.get("title") as! String
                self.artiklerArray.append(artiklerTitleLabel)
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
...
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ArtiklerCell", for: indexPath) as! ArtiklerCell
    let artikler = artiklerArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.artiklerTitleLabel.text = artikler
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Don't mind my last comment about no access to the database! My rules for open access had a time limit of one month from creation, which ended literally yesterday. Fixed that now

Comment: Now I only get the error message `Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x7fff87a5f6b8) to 'NSURL'`. I get that I haven't done any coding to make xcode understand I want the url entered as a string in Firestore to be read as an actual URL and downloaded as the images for artiklerImageView, but I don't get how I should do this! I've googled around and tried out a few things now but I can't solve it :/

Comment: If you want to convert String to URL then you should do it like `URL(string: "your string here")`. The error is literally telling you should do so.

Comment: I get that, but I don't know how to set the `"your string here"` to be the 'imageURL' string I am fetching from the database for every single cell. Also, I understand that there is more I need to do in order to set the URL as the image for the UIImageView, but again, I don't know how to do this. I'm sorry for my inability to grasp this and thanks for bearing with me so far! As this is suddenly a new problem than the one I stated originally, I should probably publish a new question regarding this.

Comment: I'll try to explain as much as I can here. Here your situation is like this you've stored an array of strings for title and imageUrl which is in the form of a `Dictionary` (given that there are no issues in that part). You are trying to loop through each element and appending that into an array just as you've given here. So now you have say two arrays of strings which is corresponding to title and image. In the `cellForItem` you should set the corresponding title and imageUrlString corresponding to `indexPath.row`. For the urlString you should cast it to url then fetch the image.