# tableview swift uikit with firestore array

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, uikit, tableview

hello I have a problem creating a table view from firestore array of dictionary.

Note that the table view has the first cell that is a custom cell

for me the problem is because firestore array has only one dictionary as you could see here that is the the result of a print of the array plantDataArray

```
print("PLANT DATA ARRAY: \(plantDataArray)")
```

and I obtain this

```
PLANT DATA ARRAY: [Pietribiasi.PlantData(plantId: "C3884CIP01", plantType: "CIP", actualStatus: "WASHING", actualRecipe: "22")]
```

this is how I get the data from firestore and I put them on plantDataArray

```
func loadPlantData() {
        db.collection("plantsData").whereField("plantId", isEqualTo: "C3884CIP01").getDocuments() { [self]
            querySnapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }else{
                self.plantDataArray = querySnapshot!.documents.compactMap({PlantData(dictionaryPlantData: $0.data()) })
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.detailTableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
        }
```

after I use this function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       
        
        return plantDataArray.count
    }
```

and after this for generating the table view cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        print("INDEX ROW: \(indexPath.row)")
        print("PLANT DATA ARRAY: \(plantDataArray)")
        let customCell = detailTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MyDetailTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! MyDetailTableViewCell
        customCell.selectionStyle = .none
        let cell = detailTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DetailDefaultCell", for: indexPath)
        
       
        switch indexPath.row {
        
        case 0:
            if plantDataArray[indexPath.row].plantType == "CIP"{
                customCell.configure(imageName: "CIP")
            } else if plantDataArray[indexPath.row].plantType == "PASTEURIZATION"{
                customCell.configure(imageName: "PASTEURIZATION")
            }
            return customCell
        case 1:
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Actual Status:"
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = plantDataArray[indexPath.row].actualStatus
            cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.gray
            return cell
        default:
            return cell
        }
    }
```

but it generate only the first cell case 0 because plantDataArray.count is 1 so how I can solve this problem? It seams that I have to count the dictionary element and not the array of dictionary. Or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: for doc in querySnapshot!.documents {　}

Comment: sorry what you mean?

Comment: Are you trying to create two cells for each entry in `plantDataArray`? You are currently specifying only one row per entry in `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)`. Instead, you would need to `return plantDataArray.count * 2`.

Comment: I need to create a row for each entry in plantDataArray so in that case would be a row for plantType (this one custom cell) another row for for plantId another for actualStatus another for actualRecipe except for the first one plantType the other would be not custom cell so I obtain a table view with the first row different to the other and this is the problem because I create the first row and make a return and after I don’t have other elements in the array to count

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a row for each of the key value pairs in `plantDataArray` retrieved from Firestore. Currently, only "`plantType`" is shown instead of others. I think this is the intended behavior. Swift documentation for [UITableView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource). Function `tableView(UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection: Int) -> Int` tells the data source to return the number of rows in a given section of a table view. In this case, you are returning "`plantDataArray.count`", which is 1 in this case. This means that the table view only contains 1 row, which makes sense why "`switch indexPath.row`" only returns case 0, as there is only 1 row in the view.

If you want to show all components in the same row, you will need to define the different properties in the `tableViewCell`. If you want the data to show in different rows, then you need to specify the exact number of rows, i.e. the number of keys in the plant data object.

For more information You can refer to the StackOverflow [case1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62280008/save-array-in-firestore-and-display-it-in-the-uitableview-in-swift) and [case2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62244937/how-to-populate-a-tableview-with-data-from-firebase-firestore) where a similar issue related to  population of tableview with data from firebase firestore has been discussed.

Comment: @NicolaRigoni Posted an answer, Is it helpful?